# How to disable TinyMCE from removing span tags

Tags: tinymce

I am posting Word generated HTML to WordPress via XMLRPC.  Before I go to post.php, the format is correctly preserved in the database.  TinyMCE performs its magic and I lose quite a few formatting details.
The main issue i am seeing is that `<span>` tag with style information surrounding other elements are stripped out.  I have verified that these tags are indeed removed by TinyMCE and not Kses.
Is there a way to prevent TinyMCE from altering the HTML?  I have tried

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinymce_init');

function tinymce_init( $init ) {
    $init['extended_valid_elements'] .= ', span[style|id|nam|class|lang]';
$init['verify_html'] = false;
    return $init;
}
```

which didn't help.  According to TinyMCE [documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3averify_html), "verify_html"

*This option enables or disables the element cleanup functionality. If you set this option to false, all element cleanup will be skipped but other cleanup functionality such as URL conversion will still be executed.*

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't find the `extended_valid_elements` option in the settings panel for TinyMCE advanced, but adding the following to my `functions.php` solved it:

```
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
    $opts = '*[*]';
    $initArray['valid_elements'] = $opts;
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $opts;
    return $initArray;
} add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

[Source](http://www.leighton.com/blog/stop-tinymce-in-wordpress-3-x-messing-up-your-html-code)

Answer (score 4):

I almost always use the [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced) plugin - there is an admin page (Settings->TinyMCE Config) that let you add supported tags using the `extended_valid_elements` option.  Simply add `span` and whatever other tags you don't want removed and enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, TinyMCE Advanced does exactly the same thing as my code above to add extended_valid_elements.  But i will it with the plugin.  Maybe I there is a bug some where in my code.

Comment: Install it and try it out - if it works, then the problem is your code.  If it doesn't, something else is overriding it at the plugin or theme level.

Comment: I couldn't find a place in the latest version of TinyMCE Advanced to add elements

Comment: That's not surprising, since this post is 3 1/2 years old.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [TinyMCE Advanced plugin](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced), there is a companion plugin called [TinyMCE Advanced Configuration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-tinymce-configuration/), with which you can change config settings, like extended_valid_elements option.